# C# pass date to Oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime

I am passing a date (DateTime.Now) from C# code to Oracle procedure. I wanted to retrieve all the values from table between

**DateTime.Now - 1 11:10:00 AM to DateTime.Now 11:09:59 AM**

How do I write a oracle condition for this?

Note: Column 'CreateDate ' is a Date

I have this right now..

```
 CreateDate >= TO_DATE(to_char(in_CreateDate), 'DD-MON-YY') - 1
 and CreateDate <  TO_DATE(to_char(in_CreateDate), 'DD-MON-YY') + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do math on the date as you suggest. Here's a quick example (you can substitute your DateTime.Now and proper format string instead of my hardcoded example):

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('05-DEC-2011 05:31:32 PM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM'))
    + 11/24 + 10/(24*60) AS MyDate FROM dual;

MYDATE                    
------------------------- 
05-DEC-11 11:10:00 AM
```

Notice how I'm taking the input date, truncating it (to get the date without the time) and then adding the hours and minutes to that base date.

You can expand on this to use the `BETWEEN` keyword and get this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN TRUNC(TO_DATE('05-DEC-2011 05:31:32 PM', 
  'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')) + 11/24 + 10/(24*60) - 1
AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('05-DEC-2011 05:31:32 PM', 
  'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')) + 11/24 + 10/(24*60);
```

Or, if you're always passing `DateTime.Now` you can just use the date from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table    
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) + 11/24 + 10/(24*60) - 1
AND TRUNC(sysdate) + 11/24 + 10/(24*60);
```

Comment: Is there way to avoid 'TRUNC'?

Comment: @CoolArchTek Sure. Just omit the time portion of the Date. Or even use a DateTime object that has the specific time you'd like, 11:10 AM, as part of it already. But if you're intent on using `DateTime.Now` you need to replace the time captured in that (whenever it's called) with the specific time you are wanting to use. And that's either with `TRUNC()` or a format string that doesn't capture the time.

Answer (score 1):

The default in Oracle of - and + operators for dates is to use days.

CreateDate between (in_CreateDate-1) and (in_CreateDate+1) should work.

If the issue is that you really want stuff created on that day, but timestamps are messing you up, Oracle - operator only looks at number of days by default so you can use

where in_CreateDate-CreateDate=0

(please note that I normally use sql server, so I can't test this; this is based on reading Oracle documentation)

Answer (score 1):

To manage oracle datetime i've used OracleCommand and parameters.
for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date >= :date
```

using OracleCommand you can do this:

```
OracleCommand myOracleCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date >= :date", myOracleConnection);
myOracleCommand.Parameters.Add(":date", OracleDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate;
...
```

I think this is the best way to pass parameters because Oracle provide a set of instruction to convert query and execute it on server.